# Cocos2d 1.0.0 Differences between past versions

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so got a book today written by Steffen Itterheim and stright away my template files look different to what they are in the book. HelloWorldScene.mm vs HelloWorldLayer.mm what is the difference, even the code inside looks different.

Am i right in thinking every scene can have many layers. So the thing I am struggling with is how come layers now have their own class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Cocos2d on its 0.8 version, I am pretty sure it has changed a lot, however it has always been the case that an scene can have as many layers as you want, and yes it is recommended you use a file for each layer this makes your code easier to mantain.

You will for example have in your scene usually at least this 3 layers per scene:

> 1. Background Layer (static content)
> 2. Objects Layer (For everything that moves)
> 3. HUD Layer (Heads up display for the buttons and stuff)

Comment: on the object layer, wud i have my users character and NPC's on the same layer or different layers? also there is no scene class .mm in my template, just the layer file.

Comment: @Mintuz Yes you would generally want those on the same layer, if there is no scene class then you will need to create one, and then add the layers to the scene.

Comment: You don't have to though.  My current in dev game actually uses a separate layer for projectiles that is on top of my normal action layer.  I also have a UI layer and several developer tools layers.